# Using Wordpress and Gravity Forms as a front end for querying a database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I have a project that I'd like to integrate into a wordpress site that I run. I realize that wordpress isn't the best way to do this- but it's what I have at the moment.

My project involves taking archival data, uploading it into a relational database, and then being able to query it. the data is in the form of 
"reports" each of which have mixed data- ship's names, people's names, locations, all kinds of things.

so I have  created a database where I'm uploading all the data- a MySQL database. Because I have phpmyadmin access, adding the 10 or 12 tables or whatever it turns out to be will be extremely easy. I'm not worried about that.

My problem, however, is programming the front end.
The idea is this

Page (not post) 1: User chooses which 1 of a number of pre-set queries they'd like to run (IE retrieve a report, get all data for 1 ship, for 1 officer, 1 location etc), as well as a date range.. (I'm planning to use Gravity Forms for this part)

Page 2: based on what was done the first time, the tables I've added to the WPDB is queried, and whatever is selected is used to populate a drop-down list from which the user can use choose the ship/officer/location etc.

This will result in another query, and the result of which will be the user will be taken to another page where a PDF will be generated of the retrieved data that they can look at/save.

I've looked hard but I can't see any plugins that will actually do this- lots of plugins *writing* to the DB (or custom tables), but not that focus on retrieving and displaying data from custom tables.

Now, I've seen a bunch of conflicting information
1) That I should do this via adding functions to the theme (Bangkok Press) functions.php file- which I undrestand in concept- but I don't understand how I could then call them

2) I can create a custom plugin- If I could, I'd love to modify Gravity Forms so that the when the form is submitted, a query is triggered that retrieves from the DB- I know I could write the code, I'm just not sure *where* I would modify the code.

3) I've seen tutorials that talk about custom pages and page templates and putting PHP and HTML in them- I did write a version of this on my home dev server that is just PHP and HTML- if I could put that into a custom page and modify it so that it a) works with the template and b) uses the Wordpress hooks (such as the WPDB object) that would be fine with me too.

I'm going to say again- I know that Wordpress is not the ideal platform for that. At the moment, I don't have the option to change to another platform.

I'm sure that what I want to do is possible- I'm interested in what's the best way to achieve this- and what's probably the easiest way to achieve this (which doesn't have to be the most permanent- I'm looking to take this project to show what I mean by the idea, and then work on a better version after that)

I appreciate all advice, thanks.

Comment: Please, visit [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)